# Encrypt and Decrypt data using same function in C

Tags: c, string, encryption

Is there any function that, for a given non encrypted input, return an encrypted data and for a encrypted input returns the decrypted data?

Somethin like this...

```
char *text = "This text is being encrypted.";
crypto(text);
//Now "text" is equal to "uhabD143Adev9123CAegawgawash"
crypto(text);
//Now "text" is equal to "This text is being encrypted."
```

There is no real use for it. Only for demonstration. I won't use it on a real aplication.

Comment: The basic XOR encryption does this. There may be more: search for *symmetrical* encryption code.

Comment: Other symmetric encryption algorithms that are widely used are DES, 3DES, and AES.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Comment: There are too many functions that do this. A simple XOR encryption as shown by Mux is easy, but insecure. Basically all stream ciphers operate this way including RC4 or AES in CTR mode or a One Time Pad.

Answer (score 1):

If same function can encrypt and decrypt it's not actually encryption :) Anyway xor should work fine:

```
void crypto(char* text, char key) {
  for (; *text; ++text) *text ^= key;
}
```